# How to disable Hibernate 3.0 XML Editor in Eclipse?

Tags: xml, eclipse, hibernate, jboss, editor

I had to install JBoss Tools in my work environment, and JBoss Tools includes Hibernate Tools.
So now the *.hbm.xml are opened in the Hibernate 3.0 XML Editor, under its "Tree" view. And I don't like it, I prefer raw xml ("Source" view).

I had the same problem with Maven's pom.xml opening in its "Overview" view (such Maven editor through m2e-wtp I guess). To let them be opened in the "Source" view, I just had to check this option "Open XML page in the POM editor by default" in the preferences Maven > User Interface.
But Hibernate doesn't have such preferences in Eclipse.

So how do I configure to get all *.hbm.xml opened in the "Source" view?

PS:
Win 7
Eclipse Juno R2
JBossAS Tools 2.4.1 (+ Hibernate Tools 3.6.0)

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `General` -> `File Associations` and associate `Text Editor` as the default editor to `*.hbm.xml` files.

Comment: The problem is `*.hbm.xml` isn't added to the file associations, even if I try several times. So I can't configure it.

Comment: `*.xml` wasn't there either, but when I added it, I saw around 15 pre-defined content-type-related locked configurations, including (at the end of the list) Hibernate 3.0 XML Editor and Hibernate Configuration 3.0 XML Editor. See this screenshot: http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/6484/9mj.png

Comment: It seems this was an idea around 7-8 years ago but never implemented in Eclipse: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=85765

Comment: Also I found this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=101082
It seems adding *.hbm.xml is not possible due to limitations.